# Text overflow clipping, trying to learn CSS

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to learn a little CSS trick using Text overflow: clip.

My aim is to create a title, of which the first one-and-a-half characters are visible, and the rest is clipped off. Using a small tilted divider line and the rest of the text has the first character clipped off.

I am stuck on how to make this look good and I have only managed to make the text clipped using a px or percentage value. I have not yet managed to get it clipped in an angle. -What would be the best way to tackle this?

Here I've included an example of what I want to try and write. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example
[image: Example]

Thanks! Wick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using css `clip-path` . Eg:

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

You can read more about it in the MDN docs and modify as per use.

Comment: This not answer the question...

Comment: _My aim is to create a title, of which the first one-and-a-half characters are visible, and the rest is clipped off_
, This is what I answered to.